# Borders not lining up correct in tabs

Tags: css

I have tabs when is current It adds a border top, border left and border right.

The border left and border right when shown seem to over hang the .tabs border-bottom.

[image]

> **Question** how can I make sure that tab is has class **.current** the
>   border-left and border-right will be even with the **.tabs** border
>   bottom.

**[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/wolfgang1983/pen/LWpaLW)**

CSS

```
.tabs {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e6e8;
    margin-top: 3rem;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.tabs a {
    padding: 15px;
}

.tabs a.current {
    background: #fff;
    color: #222;
    border-top: 3px solid #ef4123;
    border-left: 1px solid #e4e6e8;
    border-right: 1px solid #e4e6e8;
}
```

Html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
      <div class="tabs">
        <a href="" class="current">Profile</a>
        <a href="" class="">Activity</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the links to `inline-block` so that any of their vertical padding/margin/borders will properly affect other elements in the layout, remove the bottom padding on `.tabs`, and I would use `translateY()` to push the element down 1px so it overlaps the border on `.tabs`

```css
.tabs {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e6e8;
    margin-top: 3rem;
}

.tabs a {
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateY(1px);
}

.tabs a.current {
    background: #fff;
    color: #222;
    border-top: 3px solid #ef4123;
    border-left: 1px solid #e4e6e8;
    border-right: 1px solid #e4e6e8;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
      <div class="tabs">
        <a href="" class="current">Profile</a>
        <a href="" class="">Activity</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the `padding-bottom` for `tabs a`

```css
.tabs {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e6e8;
    margin-top: 3rem;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.tabs a {
    padding: 15px 15px 12px 15px;
}

.tabs a.current {
    background: #fff;
    color: #222;
    border-top: 3px solid #ef4123;
    border-left: 1px solid #e4e6e8;
    border-right: 1px solid #e4e6e8;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
      <div class="tabs">
        <a href="" class="current">Profile</a>
        <a href="" class="">Activity</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```